# Problem using LINQ queries with GetItemLinqQueryable for CosmosDB

Tags: c#, sql, linq, asp.net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I am having a challenge using linq queries towards a CosmosDB container, and wonder if someone has some tips.

The container is called Departments, has several entries of "Departments", and every department has a nested array "Employees" with employee-"objects", which can be empty if there is no employee.

```
{
    "Name": "Microsoft",
    "Employees": [
        {
            "Firstname": "Lars",
            "Lastname": "Larsen",
            "Startdate": "2017-01-01T00:00:00",
            "Enddate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
            "Birthdate": "1983-01-10T00:00:00",
            "DepartmentID": "b70ab2b6-58d7-45bb-9b13-49f7d97a8aea",
            "Department": null,
            "PositionID": "1ba094a4-ce2e-463c-b45e-a81231070ed8",
            "Position": null,
            "id": "68991651-400c-427b-8839-3f1bcfc72054"
        },
        {
            "Firstname": "Knut",
            "Lastname": "Knutsen",
            "Startdate": "2019-06-15T00:00:00",
            "Enddate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
            "Birthdate": "1992-01-10T00:00:00",
            "DepartmentID": "b70ab2b6-58d7-45bb-9b13-49f7d97a8aea",
            "Department": null,
            "PositionID": "3ba04314-02ff-4603-b80e-b71e316e9c37",
            "Position": null,
            "id": "e106fbc7-c791-446e-a163-a5d29512980e"
        }
    ],
    "id": "b70ab2b6-58d7-45bb-9b13-49f7d97a8aea",
    "_rid": "qwN-AML8frwCAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/qwN-AA==/colls/qwN-AML8frw=/docs/qwN-AML8frwCAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"00000000-0000-0000-9594-5efd0a9f01d6\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1601296753
```

My goal is to return only a list of the employees, regardless of the department.
In the backend C# code with a query string "SELECT * FROM ch in c.Employees" it works perfectly.

This is the code with SQL string that is working:

```
var query = "SELECT * FROM ch in c.Employees";

        var queryDefinition =
            new QueryDefinition(
                query);

        var setIterator =
            _container.GetItemQueryIterator<Employee>(
                queryDefinition);

        var entityList = new List<Employee>();

        while (setIterator.HasMoreResults)
        {
            entityList.AddRange(await setIterator.ReadNextAsync());
        };

        return entityList;
```

And this following code rewrite works with a LINQ-query, but I perform it AFTER retrieving all employees, which is unnecessary when Ill add filtering later on to get specific employees by department,position etc. Here is the working example:

```
using (FeedIterator<Department> setIterator = _container.GetItemLinqQueryable<Department>().ToFeedIterator())
        {
            var entityList = new List<Department>();

            while (setIterator.HasMoreResults)
            {
                entityList.AddRange(await setIterator.ReadNextAsync());
            };

            var employeeList = entityList.SelectMany(c => c.Employees).ToList();

            return employeeList;
        }
```

But if I move the linq query as part of the GetItemLinqQueryable, I get an error "IQueryable does not contain a definition for 'ToFeedIterator' and also an error because it cannot convert from Department to Employee.

This has the errors on the .SelectMany(c => c.Employees) and await setIterator.ReadNextAsync(), but dont know how to visualize it. But heres the code.

```
using (FeedIterator<Department> setIterator = _container.GetItemLinqQueryable<Department>()
            .SelectMany(c => c.Employees)
            .ToFeedIterator<Department>())
        {
            var entityList = new List<Employee>();

            while (setIterator.HasMoreResults)
            {
                entityList.AddRange(await setIterator.ReadNextAsync());
            };

            return entityList;
        }
```

Does someone know if its possible to do all of this and with filtering in the linq in one query attached  to the cosmosDB, so I dont need to get out all employees and then filter?

Thanks!
Hope my post is not too confusing, I tried to make it quite clear.

Answer (score 3):

Please try this:

```
using (FeedIterator<Employee> setIterator = container.GetItemLinqQueryable<Department>()
                .SelectMany(c => c.Employees)
                .ToFeedIterator<Employee>())
            {
                var entityList = new List<Employee>();

                while (setIterator.HasMoreResults)
                {
                    entityList.AddRange(await setIterator.ReadNextAsync());
                };

                return entityList;
            }
```

Result:

[image]

By the way, below code can also work fine.

```
var entityList = container.GetItemLinqQueryable<Department>(true).SelectMany(c => c.Employees).ToList<Employee>();
return entityList;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
 var queryOptions = new QueryRequestOptions
            {
                MaxConcurrency = -1,
                PartitionKey = PartitionKey.None;// May be null
            };

             _container.GetItemLinqQueryable<Department>(requestOptions: queryOptions)
            .SelectMany(c => c.Employees)
            .ToFeedIterator<Department>())
```